# Is it possible to move .tmux.conf to ~/.config folder?

Tags: tmux

I want to move the `.tmux.conf` file from `~` to `./config/...`, but I'm not sure about whether this would lead to tmux would not know about this location. So where are the alternative location(s) where tmux will source its `.tmux.conf` file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting with `tmux` version 3.1, `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` works as an alternative to `~/.tmux.conf`. Notice that it *cannot* be a hidden file in that directory.

Comment: This answer is non-trivial because it seems `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` is not mentioned in the documentation like `man tmux` (at least for now). It's in the changelog and in `Makefile.am`. `tmux` 3.2 checks `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmux/tmux.conf` as well.

Comment: this is documented now: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/pull/3023 hopefully it'll start appearing in distro man-pages soon

Comment: and the contents of ~/.tmux? Also into .config/tmux?

Answer (score 3):

Niing's answer is a great solution, and I would recommend it as the self-accepted answer.

For anyone using a `tmux` release prior to 3.1, or who wants to use a location other than `~/.tmux.conf` or `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`, it is also possible to specify an arbitrary location for the configuration when starting with `tmux -f <file_location>` (e.g. `tmux -f ~/.config/tmux.conf`).  You can, of course, wrap this in a shell function, an alias, or a shell script to make it quicker to type.

This works great for specifying alternative configurations that you may need only occasionally.  For example, I have a `~/.tmux.posh.conf` that sets PowerShell as the default shell for newly created windows (on Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Comment: Thank you for helping me explain the mechanism behind the scene, I just tried-and-error without explanation yesterday.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm curious: why should a shell function preferred over an alias? What's the benefit? :)

Comment: @mh166 Great question - I wish I could recall what prompted me to type that 2 years ago.  Doesn't make any sense to me at this point either! ;-).  I'll remove it, and add it back (with explanation) if I remember why I thought that.  Thanks!

Comment: @mh166 Might have just been bad editing on my part, where I started out with something like *"alias (preferably) or shell script"*, added the *"shell function"* part, and then forgot to remove or move the *"(preferably)"*.  That happens to me every so often.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds No problem at all, could be me, too. :D Was worth a try though, could've been something new to learn. =]